# How to update datatable using Ajax in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, datatables

I have a table that performs a CRUD operation using ajax, but I am new to ajax.  I have made the table interactive with the jquery datatable, but it is not working correctly.  I can add and edit data to the table and it appears, but when I sort the data the new/updated data disappears until I reload the page.

I think I know what the problem is, but I have not been able to solve it.
views.py

```
def case_list(request):
    cases = Case.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('date_due')
    return render(request, 'cases/case_list.html', {'cases': cases})
```

cases.js

```
$(function () {

  /* Functions */

  var loadForm = function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: btn.attr("data-url"),
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {
        $("#modal-case").modal("show");
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#modal-case .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
      }
    });

  };

  var saveForm = function () {
    var case_formset = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: case_formset.attr("action"),
      data: case_formset.serialize(),
      type: case_formset.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {

        if (data.form_is_valid) {
          $("#case-table tbody").html(data.html_case_list);
          $("#modal-case").modal("hide");
          myTable.draw('full-reset');
        }
        else {
          $("#modal-case .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        }

      }
    })

    return false;

  };


  /* Binding */

  // Create case
  $(".js-create-case").click(loadForm);
  $("#modal-case").on("submit", ".js-data-create-form", saveForm);

  // Update case
  $("#case-table").on("click", ".js-update-case", loadForm);
  $("#modal-case").on("submit", ".js-case-update-form", saveForm);

  // Delete case
  $("#case-table").on("click", ".js-delete-case", loadForm);
  $("#modal-case").on("submit", ".js-case-delete-form", saveForm);

});
```

list.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myTable = $('#case-table').DataTable({
        });

});
</script>


h1 class="page-header">Cases</h1>

  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-create-case" data-url="{% url 'case_create' %}">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      New case
    </button>
  </p>

  <table class="table" id="case-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date due</th>

        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for case in cases %}
  <tr class = 'click-row'>
    <td><a href="{% url 'edit_case' case.slug %}" ></a>{{ case.date_due }}</td>   
    <td style="width: 150px">
      <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-warning btn-sm js-update-case"
              data-url="{% url 'case_update' case.id %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
      </button>
      <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-danger btn-sm js-delete-case"
              data-url="{% url 'case_delete' case.id %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>

{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-case">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the above I tried to simply add `myTable.draw('full-reset');` as well as `myTable.ajax.reload();` in the success function as I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43070274/4296857), but it did not change the results.  I also tried `myTable.row.add(case_formset.serialize()).draw();` replacing `$("#case-table tbody").html(data.html_case_list);`

The docs have a simple example, but I do not see how to pass my above data as "ajax", since the example is a static .txt file and my data is from a context_dict and is dynamic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

Then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452949/update-datatable-with-ajax-request) seems helpful, but I am confused on a few points.
Similarly to the docs it gives the below example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": 'your url here'
    });
});
```

What is the url?  Is it the url to the page displaying the data?

It also shows

```
"ajax": ...,
"columns": [
    { "data": "email" },
    { "data": "platform" },
    { "data": "coins" },
    ...
]
```

Would my data be my context dictionary cases? I feel like this should be an easy fix, but am stumped.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var saveForm = function () {
    var case_formset = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: case_formset.attr("action"),
      data: case_formset.serialize(),
      type: case_formset.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {

        if (data.form_is_valid) {
          $("#case-table tbody").html(data.html_case_list);
          $("#modal-case").modal("hide");
              myTable.ajax.reload();
        }
        else {
          $("#modal-case .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        }

      }
    })

    return false;

  };
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Care with the code-only answers: when you can, it is better to explain what was wrong and what you did to correct it :)