# Edit jQuery Datatable fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to output a bootstrap label for one value of a field in a JQuery dataTable. This fields possible values can be '0' or '1' and depending on the result I want to decide which bootstrap label I want to output in the dataTable. Unfortunately I don't know how I can do this if statement for this case.

My JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#accountOverview').dataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/database/accounts.php",
            "data": {"action": "selectAccounts"},
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "platform" },
            { "data": "coins" },
            { "data": "profitDay" },
            { "data": "playerName" },
            { "data": "tradepileCards" },
            { "data": "tradepileValue" },
            { "data": "enabled" }
        ],
        "autoWidth": false
    });
});
```

I need to use something like this for the result of the "enabled" field:

```
if(enabled==1) <label class="label label-success">Online</label>
else <label class="label label-error">Offline</label>
```

**HTML Table:**

```
<table id="accountOverview" class="table datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>E-Mail</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Coins</th>
            <th>Profit last 24h</th>
            <th>Playername</th>
            <th>Tradepile Cards</th>
            <th>Tradepile Value</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="accountList">
        <!-- List all accounts -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The label needs to be in the field "status" = the last  each row.

Comment: Where do you want the label to go (and what input element is it labeling)? What does the `table` look like before the label is injected? What should it look like after?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the information. The table is created by the jQuery part above. The last <td></td> (aka the field status should look like this when the result of the SQL query for this field is '1': <label class="label label-success">Online</label> else: <label class="label label-error">Offline</label>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following dataTable's "draw" (which happens after AJAX loads your data), you can look up the last `td` of each row and use [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) to inject the HTML you want. So, in your case, try:

```
var apply_label=function(){
    $('#accountOverview').find('td:last-child').not(':has(.label)').each(function(){
        if( this.innerHTML==="1"){
            $(this).wrapInner('<span class="label label-success"></span>');
        }
        else {
            $(this).wrapInner('<span class="label label-danger"></span>');
        }
    });
};
$('#accountOverview').dataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/database/accounts.php",
        "data": {"action": "selectAccounts"},
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "email" },
        { "data": "platform" },
        { "data": "coins" },
        { "data": "profitDay" },
        { "data": "playerName" },
        { "data": "tradepileCards" },
        { "data": "tradepileValue" },
        { "data": "enabled" }
    ],
    "autoWidth": false,
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
        apply_label();
    }
});
```

Notes:

1. I think you want `span` (not `label`).
2. I think you want [`.label-danger`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels) (not `.label-error`).

[Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/wrkkbcf1/.](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/wrkkbcf1/)

Comment: Thanks for this idea! I tried this but it didn't work for me. I guess it is because I loaded all the data via an Ajax Request and it is looking for the tds before the datatable is fully created or something? Its just doing nothing.

Comment: Is the URL to what you are working on public? Can I take a peek?

Comment: I'd need the link to the page that imports the AJAX (due to cross-domain security limitations, I can't just plug your URL into the jsFiddle).

Comment: Updated answer to use `drawCallback` (https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback). Tested this solution against your prototype and it works.

Comment: This works nice. Thanks your this work and sorry for accepting the answer so late.