# Manipulate result for dataTable field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I would like to output a bootstrap label for one value of a field in a JQuery dataTable. The fields possible values can be '0' or '1' and depending on this result I want to decide which bootstrap label I want to output in the dataTable. I wonder how I can realize the if statement depending on the result of the field "enabled" and how I can fill the field with my html code:

My JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#accountOverview').dataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/database/accounts.php",
            "data": {"action": "selectAccounts"},
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "email" },
            { "data": "platform" },
            { "data": "coins" },
            { "data": "profitDay" },
            { "data": "playerName" },
            { "data": "tradepileCards" },
            { "data": "tradepileValue" },
            { "data": "enabled" }
        ],
        "autoWidth": false
    });
});
```

I need to use something like this for the result of the "enabled" field:

```
if(enabled==1) <label class="label label-success">Online</label>
else <label class="label label-error">Offline</label>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit jQuery Datatable fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465239/edit-jquery-datatable-fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your `<td class="enabled>`

DUMMY HTML CODE:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>i</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td class="enabled">0</td></tr>
           <tr><td class="enabled">1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and add manipulate via javascript:

```
var a  = document.getElementsByClassName('enabled');

for (var i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {


    if (a[i].textContent == 1) {
       a[i].innerHTML = '<label class="label label-success">Online</label>';
        }
    else {
        a[i].innerHTML = '<label class="label label-error">Offline</label>';
    }

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mo85rsh2/1)

Comment: And how can I make sure that the this row has the class "enabled" by creating the datatable via JQuery ? I checked my HTML code and it hasnt any classes assigned yet :/

Comment: Do you create the table via html or is jQuery datatables creating it all?

Comment: The jQuqery is doing it since I get all my content via an Ajax Request