# datatables columnDefs not working: jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

My datatable loads perfectly except the columndefs do not work.
Anybody got a clue?
Please help. I just want to add a click event to every cell in column 1. I get no errors either.
It works in this example on the end column...https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

```
var table =  $mytable.DataTable( {            
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": url_string,
                "cache": true,
                "columnDefs": [ 
                {"targets": 1,"data": null,"defaultContent": "<button>Select Image ID</button>"} ,  

                ]
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great post on stack overflow that really helped.
and changed it to suit me this is the post [Edit jQuery Datatable fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465239/edit-jquery-datatable-fields)

And here is what I have working for me. I was concentrating too much on the API and less on just Jquery. The trick was execute the jquery after "drawCallback":

Credit to @Jeromy French

```
var table =  $spr_cnt_tbl.DataTable( {            
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": url_string,
                "cache": true,
                "columnDefs": [ 
                {"targets": 1,"data": null,"defaultContent": "<button>Select Image ID</button>"} ,  

                ]
            },
            "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            apply_label();
            }
        });

        var apply_label=function(){
        $spr_cnt_tbl.find("td:nth-child(2)").not(':has(.label)').each(function(){
        if( this.innerHTML===""){
            $(this).wrapInner("<button class=btn btn-success id='sel_img' type='button'>Select Image</button>");
        }
        else {
            $(this).wrapInner('<span class="label label-success"></span>');
        }
        });
        };
    });
});
```